# finding distutils installation directories after installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, distutils

Distutils allow users to fine-tune installation paths with `setup.py` options such as `--prefix`, `--install-purelib`, `--install-scripts`, `--install-data` etc.  But **how do I find the value given to these options *after* installation**?

I've read some discussions here on stackoverflow, but could find no references to the values of these `setup.py` options.

My specific problem is:

- I need to access a file setup by the `datafiles=` install option

  - → Which goes to `--install-data`, default `--prefix` (which, by the way, doesn't match `sys.prefix` like the docs say);
- From a script installed via `scripts`

  - → Which goes to `--install-scripts`, default `--prefix` + `/bin`.

I've been looking at `..` relative from the scripts' directory, but this broke for users on a different system.  If I could query the value of the installation options, it would work for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pkgutil.get_data()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) to access datafiles without fiddling with install paths.

```py
import pkgutil
contents_of_datafile = pkgutil.get_data(__name__, 'data_you_installed/datafile.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to look inside the library directory (i.e. `--install-purelib`), not in the data directory (set by `--install-data`).  In other words, it's about the distutils.core.setup `package_data` option, not the `data_files` option.

But I'm thinking of giving up and putting the file inside `package_data` anyway.  It's a bit icky (because it's a `config.ini` and should therefore be in `etc/`), but at least I can be sure to find it from the library files.

Comment: "It's a bit icky" is coincidentally also the motto of distutils.